# MATLAB: How to NOT get the first element but a random index from "max" when there are multiple maximums?

Tags: matlab

I have the following code:

```
[~,ind]=max(Defender.Q,[],6);
```

`Defender.Q` is a HUGE multidimensional matrix.

When there are multiple maximums in the 6th dimension of `Defender.Q`, the `max` function
is giving me the index of the first of these multiple maximums. I want to get an index
that is randomized between multiple maximums. Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the size of `Defender.Q`?

Comment: Do these maximums have the same value, or are you talking about _local_ maximums?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this is a bit involved, but you can get the indices of all the maxima, and then randomly pick one using `randi` and `accumarray`:

```
%# (1) Find the maxima

%# if you are interested in the global maximum
%# that may occur multiple times along dimension 6
[maxVal,maxIdx] = max(Defender.Q(:));

%# ALTERNATIVELY

%# if you are interested in local maxima along dimension 6
maxVal = max(Defender.Q,[],6);
maxIdx = find(bsxfun(@eq,Defender.Q,maxVal));

%# (2) pick random maximum for each 5D subarray

%# this assumes that there is no dimension #7 etc
%# In case there is, you need to add a column of ones
%# and then d7 etc to second input of accumarray

%# find row, col, etc subscripts of the maxima
[d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6] = ind2sub(size(Defender.Q),maxIdx);

%# create a 5-d array, containing one random index
%# from the maxima along dimension 6, or NaN
randIdx = accumarray([d1,d2,d3,d4,d5],d6,[],@(x)x(randi(length(x))),NaN);
```

Comment: Double checked my answer, it was flawed. I'm removing the downvote (unfortunately I cannot un-downvote unless this answer is edited).

Comment: @ssjeitan: Kudos to you for admitting an error. I'll edit my answer to make it clearer what the two options mean. Also, I do have to parse the huge array twice, but I haven't found a good way to avoid this if it is the local maxima along dimension 6 that are requested (in the linear case it's indeed not necessary, so I'm fixing that as well). FYI: I initially wrote the exact same answer as you did, before I tested it on a 3D array and realized that it won't work.